# pathinfo method equivalent for Dart language

Tags: dart

In PHP there is a [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function that allows for example to get the filename in a path

```php
$filename = pathinfo('/some/path/filename.txt', PATHINFO_BASENAME),
// $filename = 'filename.txt'
```

I was wondering if there is a similar function in dart.

Because right now the only way I can think to do this is:

- with a regex
- using `'/some/path/filename.txt'.split('/')` and get the last element

### Edit

I'm asking this question because I will have to get the filename of a bunch of paths (multiple thousands), I'm looking to find the most performant way.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/basename.html

Comment: The `path` package is not *fast*. It covers a lot of edge-cases, but at a cost. So if you *really* need speed, and you know that your paths are "easy" cases,, you can use one of the specialized variants described below. But "multiple thousands" doesn't sound like a lot in practice, every approach mentioned here can do hundreds of thousands of operations per second, some into the millions. Just reading all those paths into memory will probably take *far* longer. I'd also use `package:path` until measurements show me that the `basename` operation is a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the best possible performance for extracting file names from paths in Dart, you can use the `built-in String methods`.

```dart
void main() {
  const int iterations = 1000000;

  String filePath = '/some/path/filename.txt';

  // Method 1: Using Uri.pathSegments
  Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    Uri.parse(filePath).pathSegments.last;
  }
  stopwatch1.stop();
  print('Method 1: ${stopwatch1.elapsedMilliseconds} ms');

  // Method 2: Using string methods
  Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }
  stopwatch2.stop();
  print('Method 2: ${stopwatch2.elapsedMilliseconds} ms');

  // Method 3: Using List.last and string split
  Stopwatch stopwatch3 = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    filePath.split('/').last;
  }
  stopwatch3.stop();
  print('Method 3: ${stopwatch3.elapsedMilliseconds} ms');

  // Method 4: Using regular expressions
  Stopwatch stopwatch4 = Stopwatch()..start();
  for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'[^/]*$');
    regExp.stringMatch(filePath)!;
  }
  stopwatch4.stop();
  print('Method 4: ${stopwatch4.elapsedMilliseconds} ms');
}
```

Output:

```
Method 1: 1386 ms
Method 2: 35 ms
Method 3: 95 ms
Method 4: 256 ms
```

Comment: This assumes that the path separator is `/`, which it isn't on Windows. (But can mostly be fixed by using `r'\'` instead on Windows).
The `package:path` takes care of that. It's not as fast as what you have here, but it covers all the edge cases that you might not think about.
(I'd use `Uri.file(path)` for a local file-system path, because URI paths are a different kind of beast, and if performance is the goal, you should create the RegExp outside of the loop).
Here's an optimized version of the benchmark: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=9b85b4354413f5ec23c25e1ae39a8eee
(Nothing beats #2)